# basic_string of unsigned char Value Type

Tags: c++, string, char, unsigned

So, string comes with the value type of `char`. I want a string of value type `unsigned char`. Why i want such a thing is because i am currently writing a program which converts large input of hexadecimal to decimal, and i am using strings to calculate the result. But the range of char, which is -128 to 127 is too small, unsigned char with range 0 to 255 would work perfectly instead. Consider this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef basic_string<unsigned char> u_string;
    u_string x= "Hello!";

    return 0;
}
```

But when i try to compile, it shows 2 errors, one is **_invalid conversion from const char* to unsigned const char*_** and the other is **initializing argument 1 of std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string...**(it goes on)

EDIT:
"Why does the problem "converts large input of hexadecimal to decimal" require initializing a u_string with a string literal?"
While calculating, each time i shift to the left of the hexadecimal number, i multiply by 16. At most the result is going to be 16x9=144, which surpasses the limit of 127, and it makes it negative value.
Also, i have to initialize it like this:

> x="0"; x[0] -='0';

Because i want it to be 0 in value. if the variable is null, then i can't perform operations on it, if it is 0, then i can.

So, what should i do?

Comment: Why does the problem "converts large input of hexadecimal to decimal" require initializing a `u_string` with a string literal?

Comment: @user2653125 Your edit still doesn't explain why you need a *string literal* for initialisation.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I mean, why do you care about *initialization*?

Comment: Why use strings, anyway? What's wrong with `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: @Robᵩ ah sorry. ok new edit.

Comment: Thanks. Those aren't initializations, those are assignments. So your original question doesn't really represent the problem you are actually having.

Comment: @Angew i think using string would make the program faster? Or not? Because in vectors, any time i would add a new digit on the left it would allocate a whole new memory, than assign. If i use strings i can simply use operator +?

Comment: @user2653125 And what do you think `+` on strings does? Except that `vector` would give you control of how to grow - via `reserve()`.

Comment: @Angew ok, i am feeling a bit retarded right now. So will vector<unsigned char> be the same thing as a u_string in performance? Because the faster the algorithm performs the better is for me. Would the vector do the same thing as fast as u_string?

Comment: @user2653125 It depends on what you do with it, of course. But if you just use it as a growing sequential container, it might actually be better, because it gives you the option to pre-allocate the memory and avoid reallocations.

Comment: @Angew To each x[i] i will multiply by 16, add a number up to 15, then convert the whole number in decimal by using modulo 10 and divisions by 10, and assign what's left on the left-side of the result. So you think vector would do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

String literals are `const char` and you are assigning them to a `const unsigned char`.

Two solution you have:

First, Copy string from standard strings to your element by element.

Second, Write your own [user-literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for your string class:

```
inline constexpr const unsigned char * operator"" _us(const char *s,unsigned int)
{
    return (const unsigned char *) s;
}

// OR 

u_string operator"" _us(const char *s, unsigned int len)
{
    return u_string(s, s+len);
}

u_string x = "Hello!"_us;
```

Comment: ok, how to make them be considered as const unsigned char by default?

Comment: You can not, but you can have your literals.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to make your compiler treat `char` as unsigned. There are compiler flags for this:

- MSVC: `/J`
- GCC, Clang, ICC: `-funsigned-char`

Comment: i would like to do this in the code, because i have to upload the code as a solution in an online site.